# How to replicate this css media jquery using javascript to support IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, media-queries

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px){
    #div {
        left: 500px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width:1000px){
    #div {
        left: 50%;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with a javascript / jquery method for achieving this same effect so that my site will support older versions of IE? Thanks.

Comment: you could just conditionally comment separate styles for each version of IE you have to deal with. it's not a js solution like you asked for, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all use sth like [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to check your browser's capabilities (it's not only IE that won't support media queries) and then set up something that listens for a `$(window).resize()` and changes your layout accordingly. See: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

A little like:

```
if (!Modernizr.mq('(max-width:1000px)'){
  $(window).bind('resize load',function(){ //the load will make the style rules apply on load as well (i.e. noone's resizing the window)
    if ($(window).width() > 1000){
      //layout big version
    } else {
      //layout small version
    }
  });
}
```